# Reverse percentage to get actual amount

Tags: math

I ran into scenario where my client wants to know the original amount after percentage deduction. They are collecting online donation where user enter its amount and then percentage values (bank charges and FED) are added in his amount to ensure that my client always get exact amount in his account after percentage deduction.

**For example:**

```
Donation amount = 32,000
Bank charges = 3%
FED charges = 13%

Calculation: 

Deducting bank charges = 32000 * .03 = 960
Deducting FED on bank charges = 960 * .13 = 124.80
Total = 32000 + 960 + 124.80 = 33,084.80
```

I now want to reverse the amount 33,084.80 to get the exact actual amount of 32,000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let `Bank charges = b`, `FED charges = f`  (here `b=0.03, f=0.13`)

Then

```
  Donation  + Donation * b + Donation * b * f = Total
  Donation * (1 + b + b * f) = Total
so
  Donation = Total / (1 + b + b * f)
here
  Donation = 33,084.80 / (1 + 0.03 + 0.03 * 0.13) = 33,084.80 / 1.0339 = 32,000
```

Comment: any explanation on adding 1 plz?

Comment: @codelearner - When you start with `Donation  + Donation * b + Donation * b * f = Total` you have a common factor of `Donation` in each of the three terms. So MBo has taken `Donation` out of each of the terms in the second line with `Donation * (1 + b + b * f) = Total`. The `1` is because the first term was the equivalent of `1 x Donation`.

Comment: Can someone explain this initial line `Donation + Donation * b + Donation * b * f`? How we got this?

Comment: Emm.. This is basic algebra  `Donation + Donation * b + Donation * b * f = Donation * 1 + Donation * b + Donation * b * f`, so we can get common multiplier `Donation` out of braces

Comment: Just want to know which algebra rule applies that makes this line `Donation + Donation * b + Donation * b * f`

Comment: Receiver receives donation `D`. Bank takes percent `D*b`. The last value is used to find charge `(D*b)*f`. Overall fee is sum of three values.

Comment: Thanks @MBo. Just one small question what will be the formula if actual amount is <= 8000 and after applying all bank charges and FED it adds 24 to the resulting amount. Now I want to reverse it to get exact donation amount.

Comment: For eg. if amount donated is 8000 then applying your formula I get 8000 * 1.0339 = 8271.2. Adding 24 = 8295.2. Now I want to reverse it to get 8000.

Comment: `(Total - 24) / (1 + b + b * f)`